# How to get statusBarOrientation on first view

Tags: ios, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

How does one detect the correct orientation of the application on the first view? I need to know so I can either display a portrait image or landscape image as the background.

`[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` doesn't work properly if the iPad is laid down flat on a surface.

`statusBarOrientation` doesn't seem to return the correct results for the very first view that is loaded. I tried getting the status bar orientation in the `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidLoad` and both returned **Portrait** even when in landscape.

I have confirmed that I have `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]` in my `AppDelegate.m` in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`. This is only returning the incorrect status bar orientation on the first view controller.

Note: I have also tried the `interfaceOrientation` from the `UIViewController`, ad that still returns portrait no matter what.

Any ideas how to fix this?

EDIT:

I am using the `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` to detect if it is portrait or landscape but my issue is detecting what the view actually is if UIDevice returns an orientation of flat (non portrait or landscape).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GOT IT!

I was able to do a work around by using

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

Even on view load this method is triggered if the orientation is not of `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait`.

Even if the device is flat, it seems that there is a long enough delay for the orientation to correct itself and detect whether the `UIView` is in portrait or landscape mode.

EDIT:

When `viewDidAppear` is triggered by then, `[self interfaceOrientation]` has the correct value. So if you can wait until that method, you can also get it there.

Answer (score 1):

Many applications have this issue. If the device is flat then any of the orientations is valid.

Your best bet is to use the `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` to know what the orientation is if possible for the cases where the orientation can be determined. But when it's flat, it'll just be whatever it was last.

How many times have you see people flick up their iPad to get the landscape orienation the right way around.

Comment: How do I get the last orientation? I ask because I position and image depending on screen orientation as well as the background image. If I don't have the correct orientation the view is all messed up.

Comment: If your really want to know what image to use, have you tried to get the frame of the main screen? You'll be able to see if it's portrait or landscape that way.